# Vue-resource can't get response body when HTTP error 500

Tags: rest, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm trying to handle an **HTTP 500** error using `vue-resource` (1.2.1) this way:

```
const resource = Vue.resource('items');

resource.get().then(
  (response) => {
    // Do something with response.body
  },
  (error) => {
    // Do something with error.body,
    // even if the HTTP status code is 500.
    // But for now it's null...
  }
);
```

There is nothing in `error.body`, while the actual server's response have something to say... And I really want to get this data to be displayed in a cool way for my app's users to be aware of what's going on (rather than opening dev tools and inspect network's response data).

Is there something I'm missing in Vue http config? Or maybe server-side, does my API needs to respond in a specific way? Or even respond special headers? Or, is it simply a limitation (or a bug) of vue-resource?

**EDIT**
Here is the content of `error`, picked from a console.log:

```
Response {
    body: "",
    bodyText: "",
    headers: Headers…,
    ok: false,
    status: 0,
    statusText: "",
    url: "http://my.domain/items",
    data: ""
}
```

And, the content of the actual server response (which I expected to be into error.body, but is not), picked from "network" tab in dev tools :

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "message":"this is the error message",
        "details":[],
        "stackTrace":[]
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can access the response using `error.response.data`

Comment: try to console log your errors obj and see its structure

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I already thought about doing what you said. So I edited my question to add details and show you more accurately the problem.

Comment: It's probably something wrong with your end point on the server side. could u please add the code for the server side

Comment: Server side, I'm using the PHP Slim framework running on Apache2 server on Ubuntu 16.04. I will try to add parts of code that is relevant for my question. Thanks :)